# Incorrect timestamp by date processor in elasticsearch filebeat

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am getting wrong value in @timestamp field for elasticsearch/filebeat.
My filebeat pipeline definition

```
    curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT "logger:9200/_ingest/pipeline/app_log" -d'
    {
      "description" : "Ingest pipeline for Jetty server log",
      "processors" : [
        {
          "grok": {
            "field": "message",
            "patterns": ["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (%{UUID:accessid})? \\[(?<threadname>[^\\]]+)\\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:classname} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
          }
        },
        {
          "date": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "formats": [ "yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s,SSS" ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "on_failure" : [{
        "set" : {
          "field" : "error.message",
          "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
        }
      }]
    }'
```

Simulation result for some sample logger line. ( Using logback configuration )

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST "logger:9200/_ingest/pipeline/app_log/_simulate?pretty" -d'
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "2018-03-17 22:38:39,079 bab3157d-a11c-4dba-a6d6-c47ae0de2b7f [qtp224100622-174782] INFO  i.n.core.services.cache.CacheBuilder - Key : ChIJrTTTJkdsrjsRXkrYRKRRfd8-seo-localitiesv1 is returned from cache"

      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "2017-12-12 01:14:12,079  [qtp224100622-185269] WARN  i.n.m.cache.sdk.RedisCacheProvider - No matching policy: class in.nobroker.core.domain.Token"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

The result from this simulation:

> {   "docs" : [
>       {
>         "doc" : {
>           "_index" : "_index",
>           "_type" : "_type",
>           "_id" : "_id",
>           "_source" : {
>             "accessid" : "bab3157d-a11c-4dba-a6d6-c47ae0de2b7f",
>             "@timestamp" : "2018-01-17T22:38:39.079Z",
>             "classname" : " i.n.core.services.cache.CacheBuilder",
>             "level" : "INFO",
>             "message" : "Key : ChIJrTTTJkdsrjsRXkrYRKRRfd8-seo-localitiesv1 is returned from cache",
>             "timestamp" : "2018-03-17 22:38:39,079",
>             "threadname" : "qtp224100622-174782"
>           },
>           "_ingest" : {
>             "timestamp" : "2018-03-17T15:35:35.543Z"
>           }
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "doc" : {
>           "_index" : "_index",
>           "_type" : "_type",
>           "_id" : "_id",
>           "_source" : {
>             "@timestamp" : "2017-01-12T01:14:12.079Z",
>             "classname" : " i.n.m.cache.sdk.RedisCacheProvider",
>             "level" : "WARN",
>             "message" : "No matching policy: class in.nobroker.core.domain.Token",
>             "timestamp" : "2017-12-12 01:14:12,079",
>             "threadname" : "qtp224100622-185269"
>           },
>           "_ingest" : {
>             "timestamp" : "2018-03-17T15:35:35.543Z"
>           }
>         }
>       }   ] }

Please notice that @timestamp field is totally different from timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you give wrong date formats

```
{
  "date": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "formats": [ "yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s,SSS" ]
  }
}
```

As the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) shows "mm: two-digit minutes, zero-padded if needed" instead of the month you expected.
Try

```
{
  "date": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "formats": [ "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s,SSS" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat do not have date processor. Elasticsearch has processor. To use the timestamp from the log as @timestamp in filebeat use ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch.